# Ensuring UML constraints in Java?

Tags: java, model, uml, constraints

Say that the design of my application is such that there are two classes: `Person` and `Company`. Also suppose I have defined a UML diagram that defines a one-to-many relationship between  `Person` and `Company`: every `Person` object must belong to exactly one `Company`, and a `Company` can contain many `Person`s.

What are some best practices for ensuring that this simple constraint always holds, i.e., that there is never a point in time where a `Person` object is contained in more than one `Company`? I've thought of three approaches:

1. Have perfect, bug-free code that would *never* violate any of my constaints. However, being a realist, I know that this is difficult or impossible, especially as the number of constraints grows.
2. Implement an `ensureCorrectness()` method that manually checks each and every constraint. In this example, it would loop through all `Person`s, and make sure that exactly one `Company` contained that `Person`. If not, it would print an error. I would call this method every so often.
3. Use, e.g., Hibernate to define a database schema and store the data into a database. In the schema, I can define a constraint to match the constrains in my UML diagram. Then, whenever I persists data into the database, Hibernate will check all the constraints and print an error if something's gone wrong.

But I can't help wondering if there is another, cleaner way to do this in Java, that doesn't rely on (1) perfection, (2) manual validation, or (3) a relational database. Is there a library or framework that would allow me to specify annotations in the code similar to:

`@OneToMany(Person, Company)`

Or perhaps more specifically:

`@OneToMany(Person, Company.persons)`

assuming the `Company` class had a `List<Person> persons` member variable.

And if I wanted to ensure that a person's social security number is unique across all `Person`s, I could say:

`@Unique(Person.SSN)`

**Does anything like this exist for Java?**

Answer (score 0):

The relation between a Company to Person is not difficult. Make e.g. a list with Person elements contained in Company. The one thing you have to ensure manually is that the list does not contain multiple instances of a single Person.

The other way around is more difficult. You have to manually check this (that each list does not contain multiple instances of the same Person). But you can combine it with the previous restriction:

The length of all lists of persons should be equal as the length of all lists with unique persons.

I do not have much knowledge about databases, but I would go for the second option (ensureCorrectNess) to check the manual constriction above.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no such framework or library in Java to do this automatically, and that I should just implement option (2) that I listed in my original question?

Comment: I don't know Java that well, but I don't know of such a library.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it like that in Java:

```
public class Company {
    Set<Person> persons;
    ...
    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        if (person.getCompany() != this) { // Avoiding an infinite loop between addPerson() and setCompany()
            person.setCompany(this);
            persons.add(person);
        }
    }
    public boolean removePerson(Person person) {
        return persons.remove(person);
    }
    ...
}

public class Person {
    Company company;
    public Person(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        if (this.company != null) {
            this.company.remove(this);
        }
        this.company = company;
        company.addPerson(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

In code, `Person` cannot have more than one `Company`, and `Company` has a list of `Persons`. With the `Person(Company)` constructor, `Person` has at least one company assigned.

EDIT: To modify the `Set` (no duplicates), you have to pass through the `addPerson()` method that call the `Person.setCompany()` method. This method will remove the `Person` from previous `Company` list and add him to the new `Company` list.

In `setCompany()`, you have to call to `addPerson()`, because programmers can assign directly a `Person` to a `Company` without calling first to `addPerson()`.

Comment: But what's to stop a `Person` object from being in two `Company`'s `persons` lists?

Comment: So basically you're saying that there is no such framework or library in Java to check these kinds of constraints automatically, and that the best solution is to sprinkle to constraint logic throughout the code? So if I had 300 of these constraints, there would be no way to centralize them all in one place?

Comment: I understand your problem, but I don't know any framework that would control these types of constraints. It doesn't mean that it doesn't exist, as I don't know all the existing frameworks, there are so many...

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for #1, in combination with encapsulation. This way, the amount of code that has to be 100% bug free is very small

```
public class Company {
    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Person> publicPerson = Collections.unmodifiableList(persons);

    public List<Person> getPersons { return publicPersons; }

    public void addPerson(Person p) {
         ... ensure p is removed from old company
         p.setCompany(this);
         persons.add(p);
    }

}

public class Person {
    private Company company;
    /* pkg-private */ setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
}
```

Careful, this code is not threadsafe!

Notice that hibernate will only check the constraints if you save to the database. Due to caching, inconsistencies may appear.

Comment: The downside to this is solution, similar to eternay's solution, is that there is no way to isolate all the constraints into one place: they will be scattered across the codebase. If I had 300 constraints, there would be no easy to way to see/change them all in one place.

Comment: The constraints are in the model classes, where they belong. You could have a look at the properties of JavaFX, but you will get some overhead with these. That's the general problem: due to Java's static nature, you would end up with byte-code manipulations at runtime, if you want a central configuration.

Comment: I guess you're right about constraints belonging in the model classes, but I still think it would easier to write something like `@OneToMany(Person, Company.persons)` instead of implementing code to this check for me. Maybe I'm a dreamer. BTW, I don't see how JavaFX properties can help to ensure ManyToOne relationships between objects, but I'll investigate a bit deeper.

Comment: The problem with the annotation approach is that you would have to rewrite all field access bytecodes, either at compile or load time. I don't know how powerful jfx properties are, but you can do some stuff with bindings.

Answer (score -1):

first you can configure all this in the DB very easily by set the col in the db not null and the customer id unique.
you can use triggers before and after to be sure that the data is remove or added to the DB.

second option you can set all the DB on java classes by using Hash Maps to contain the data.

in my opinion the first option is more easy..

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I specifically requested a solution that does not rely on an underlying database. I'm looking for a pure-Java solution.